# Rails - Ambiguous column name: id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am currently trying to seed some test data using the following code:

```
  # add vehicle
  trim = Trim.where(:id => 1 + Random.rand(250)).first
  model_year_array = trim.model_years.all(:select => :id).collect(&:id)
  vehicle = Vehicle.create(trim_id: trim.id, model_year_id: model_year_array[Random.rand(model_year_array.length - 1)])
```

I think it's fairly self explanatory - essentially I want to get an array of the model_year ids that are applicable to the selected trim, select a random one, and use its id as the model_year_id of the vehicle.

The problem I am having is that the `trim.model_years.all(:select => :id).collect(&:id)` part is generating an error that id is ambiguous; the error is as follows:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT id FROM "model_years" INNER JOIN "model_year_trims" ON "model_years"."id" = "model_year_trims"."model_year_id" WHERE "model_year_trims"."trim_id" = 110
```

How can I reformat my code so that selecting the id gets the id of the model_year, and is thus not ambiguous?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When performing joins, you have to prefix colums that exists in several tables, such as id :

```
model_year_array = trim.model_years.all(:select => "model_years.id").collect(&:id)
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The parser does not know whether to use the column ID from one table or the other. You should have something like:

```
SELECT "model_years" ."id" 
  FROM "model_years" 
 INNER JOIN "model_year_trims" ON "model_years"."id" = "model_year_trims"."model_year_id"
 WHERE "model_year_trims"."trim_id" = 110
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be a bit more robust, you can ask your model its table_name rather than hard-coding it. This code will not break even if the table is renamed in sql.

```
model_year_array = trim.model_years.all(:select => "#{ModelYear.table_name}.id").collect(&:id)
```